# Get video chipset manufacturer in Direct3D

Tags: directx, nvidia, amd, intel

I'd need to know if the video chipset Direct3D runs on is from **Nvidia, AMD or Intel**.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This question scares me... are you trying to do some sort of branching on this, or even worse, a card database?

Comment: @Lars I'm using some vendor-specific extensions so I might use this as a first guess of which one to try. So yes, branching, what's wrong with this?

Comment: Fair enough. Usually when this kind of question appears, it's someone that hardcodes a mapping from name to capabilities that is instantly obsolete as soon as it's compiled. Such lists were the bane of software like Cedega, which exposes a fairly different set of capabilities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ha, found it with more googling.

D3D9: call [`IDirect3D9::GetAdapterIdentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and check the `VendorId` of the provided [`D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

D3D11: call [`IDXGIAdapter::GetDesc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and check the `VendorId` of the provided [`DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

Video chipsets vendor IDs, retrieved from [this list](http://www.pcidatabase.com/vendors.php?sort=id):

- Nvidia: **0x10DE**
- AMD: **0x1002**, 0x1022
- Intel: 0x163C, **0x8086**, 0x8087

In bold: the IDs mentioned in CardCaps.pdf (provided with the DirectX SDK), that add up with what Direct3D returns on actual hardware.

Comment: Hopefully you'll save some poor sap in the future some Googling. ;)